# Ansible get search domain from DNS in Ansible facts

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ansible, ansible-facts

[image]

How can I use the search domain in a variable? When I use `"{{ ansible_dns['search'] }}"` there are brackets in the output.

Comment: There can be multiple search domains, and that's why the fact is a [list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables). In short, the first one can be accessed with `"{{ ansible_dns['search'][0] }}"` and so on.

Comment: ``"{{ search.0 }}"`` is the first item of the list aka array or [sequence](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/#sequence//).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple search domains, and that's why the fact is a list. In short, the first one can be accessed with `"{{ ansible_dns['search'][0] }}"` and so on.

If there are multiple search domains and you'd like to use them in a configuration file, you can use the `join` filter with the desired "joining" character. The example below will join the search domains with a space (as it appears in `/etc/resolv.conf`):

```
"{{ ansible_dns['search'] | join(' ') }}"
```

Note: This will work with single or multiple entries in `"search": []`.